# How can I see what function argument maps to a calling argument in TypeScript / vscode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Frequently I import a TypeScript function into another file. That function has positional arguments:

```
import { doThing } from "./somefile";

doThing("banana", "lemon", "apple", "grape", "cherry");
```

I know I can hover over the function `doThing` and see its function signature.

However if the function takes more than a few arguments, it becomes difficult to line up the arguments the function is being called with, to the functions parameters.

Eg, if `somefile.ts` is:

```
export const doThing = function (one, two, three, four, five) {
  // ...
};
```

How can I know that `cherry` corresponds to the parameter `five`?

**How can I see what function argument maps to a calling argument in TypeScript / vscode?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually do it like this: I place the cursor on the argument I want to be hinted in the function call and press `shift` + `ctrl` + `space`. On a Mac the shortcut is `shift` + `command` + `space`.

(Sorry about the light theme screenshot if you mind)

[image: parameter hints]

VSCode calls this action "trigger parameter hints" and you can search for it.

Comment: Thanks! I'm surprised they don't just show this by default. Might ask as a feature request.

Comment: Ah this is so useful! Thanks. I use Ctrl + Space but if you click into the code where you're already passing params this shows a list of types/variables available, rather than the params you need to pass in. So helpful - thanks!